# How to convert from bytes to int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that to convert from `int` to `bytes` you have to do this, for example:

```
>>>a = bytes(4)
>>>print(a)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

But what do I do if I want to revert it and convert `bytes` to `int` or `float`?

I tried using:

```
int.from_bytes( a, byteorder='little')
```

and

```
int.from_bytes( a, byteorder='big', signed=True)
```

but it did not work.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? If you have a well-defined binary format, `unpack` can convert it to a native type or structure. But there are four different ways your four bytes can be interpreted so you need to know how the data is serialized first (or just guess, if this is idle curiosity).

Comment: Your problem is not reading the number back, it is storing the number.

`bytes(4)` makes an array of 4 bytes, all zeros.  Perhaps you didn't notice that the number 4 is not actually the value.  Try `bytes(9)` for example.

Comment: So,  the way to go back is just `len`  ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import struct
val = struct.unpack( '<I', b'\x00\x00\x00\x00')[0]
```

or something along the lines... control the `big/little` with `<` or `>` sign.

Here are the docs: [7.1. struct — Interpret bytes as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)