# Read an video file object from S3 and use it for further processing through Opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, amazon-s3, boto3, video-processing

```
import boto3

import cv2
import numpy as np
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
vid = (s3.Object('bucketname', 'video.blob').get()['Body'].read())
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
```

This is my code. I have a video file in an s3 bucket. I want to do some processing on it with OpenCV and I don't want to download it. So I'm trying to store that video file into `vid`. Now the problem is that `type(vid)` is `byte` which is the reason to result in this error `TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)`
 on line 6. I tried converting it into an integer or a string but was unable to.

On an attempt to convert byte to an integer: I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220161/how-to-convert-from-bytes-to-int) and was getting length issues. This is just a sample video file. The actual file I want to do processing on will be huge when converted to byte object.

On an attempt to get the object as a string and then convert it to an integer: I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087203/retrieve-s3-file-as-object-instead-of-downloading-to-absolute-system-path). Even this doesn't seem to work for me.

If anyone can help me solve this issue, I will be grateful. Please comment if anything is uncertain to you regarding my issue and I'll try to provide more details.

Comment: Since you seem to want to access the video from some web resource, you probably want some string containing a URL -- integer identifiers given to `VideoCapture` constructor are used to identify local cameras only.

Comment: The url of the video file is a force download url. I'm trying to make it viewable by altering the settings. Even though If I could make it displayable, I cannot access it via OpenCv because `VideoCapture` is only working for `https://www.example.com/myimage.mp4` and for video links like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw` it won't work. Any other possible solution please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555195/is-it-possible-to-stream-video-from-https-e-g-youtube-into-python-with-ope ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is relevant however it does not exactly solve my problem.

Comment: Hi! Did you manged to solve it? @VinayVarma

Answer (score 3):

If streaming the video from a url is an acceptable solution, I think that is the easiest solution. You just need to generate a url to read the video from.

```
import boto3
import cv2

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        
bucket = 'bucketname'      
key = 'video.blob' 
            
url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', 
                                       Params = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key}, 
                                       ExpiresIn = 600) #this url will be available for 600 seconds
    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
       
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

You should see that you are able to read and process frames from that url.

Answer (score -6):

Refer below the useful code snippet to perform various operations on S3 bucket.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
```

## for listing buckets in s3

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

## bucket creation in s3

```
my_bucket=s3.create_bucket(Bucket='Bucket Name', CreateBucketConfiguration={
    'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'
})
```

## listing down objects inside bucket

```
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('Bucket Name')
for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print (file.key)
```

## Uploading a file from current directory

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())

fileName="B01.jpg"
bucketName="Bucket Name"
file = open(fileName)
s3.meta.client.upload_file(fileName, bucketName, 'test2.txt')
```

## reading image/video from bucket

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
bucket = s3.Bucket('Bucket Name')   # bucket name
object = bucket.Object('maisie_williams.jpg')  # image name
object.download_file('B01.jpg')            #donwload image with this name
img=plt.imread('B01.jpg')              #read the downloaded image
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)              #plot the image
plt.show(imgplot)
```

## Reading from one bucket and then dumping it to another

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2')
bucket = s3.Bucket('Bucket Name')   # bucket name
object = bucket.Object('maisie_williams.jpg')  # image name
object.download_file('B01.jpg')



fileName="B01.jpg"
bucketName="Bucket Name"
file = open(fileName)
s3.meta.client.upload_file(fileName, bucketName, 'testz.jpg')
```

***If you have access keys then you can probably do the folowing***

```
keys = pd.read_csv('accessKeys.csv')
        #creating Session for S3 buckets
        session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=keys['Access key ID'][0],
            aws_secret_access_key=keys['Secret access key'][0])
        s3 = session.resource('s3')

        buck = s3.Bucket('Bucket Name')
```